# Winston daily rotate file maxSize is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

The code is below. Using winston daily rotate file a new file is not being created
When the maxSize i.e 2 mb is reached a new file is not created. What could be the problem? Is it a bug of is something wrong with my configuration? I tried adding removing extension or changing file name but it doesnt seem to be working

```js
const customLevels = {
  levels: {
    debug: 3,
    info: 2,
    error: 1,
    critical: 0,
  },
  filename: {
    debug: path.join(
      __dirname,
      `../../logs/debug/%DATE%_debug`
    ),
    info: path.join(
      __dirname,
      `../../logs/info/%DATE%_info`
    ),
    error: path.join(
      __dirname,
      `../../logs/error/%DATE%_error`
    ),
    critical: path.join(
      __dirname,
      `../../logs/critical/%DATE%_critical`
    ),
  },
};

let logger = createLogger({
  levels: customLevels.levels,

  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    }),
    format.simple()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.DailyRotateFile({
      filename: customLevels.filename.debug,
      maxsize: '2m',
      extension: '.log',
      level: 'debug',
    }),

    new transports.DailyRotateFile({
      filename: customLevels.filename.info,
      extension: '.log',
      maxsize: '2m',
      level: 'info',
    }),

    new transports.DailyRotateFile({
      filename: customLevels.filename.error,
      handleExceptions: true,
      maxsize: '2m',
      extension: '.log',
      level: 'error',
    }),

    new transports.DailyRotateFile({
      filename: customLevels.filename.critical,
      handleExceptions: true,
      extension: '.log',
      maxsize: '2m',
      level: 'critical',
    }),
  ],
  // exitOnError: false
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the key `maxsize` where it in fact should be `maxSize`. Usually keys and binding names are camelCased in JavaScript. You can see this apparent on NPM here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file

Where an example is given:

```
var transport = new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
    filename: 'application-%DATE%.log',
    datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
    zippedArchive: true,
    maxSize: '20m',
    maxFiles: '14d'
  });
```